# I am having difficulty accessing an element of my "table()" output in r

Tags: r

[image: my code and output]

dumb question, how do I access the first element of this output from table()? I need the file name and the frequency as seperate columns in my dataframe but I can only figure out how to access the frequency

Comment: If you want a data frame with one column for file names and one for frequency try `as.data.frame(table(tester))`. As a tip for asking questions here, please don't post code, data or errors as images, as these do not constitute a [mre] and make it far harder for folks here to test and verify possible solutions. Please post code as text in a code block, and provide a small data sample. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like Allan said, you need to convert the results from `table()` to `data frame`, and then you can access the columns. See the example below:

```
#sample data
set.seed(33)
tester=sample(1:10, 30, replace=T)
 [1] 10  8  6  9  2  8  9  5  5  7 10  6  2  4  1  3 10  2  5  6  9  1  3  7  1  9  2  6  7  3

table(tester)%>%as.data.frame()
   tester Freq
1       1    3
2       2    4
3       3    3
4       4    1
5       5    3
6       6    4
7       7    3
8       8    2
9       9    4
10     10    3
```